# Is it possible to create a HTML 5 application with offline storage to work on Blackberry?

Tags: html, blackberry, offlineapps

Hi would anyone know whether it is possible to create a HTML 5 application with offline storage to work on Blackberry?

Comment: What model of Blackberry?  Only some of the newer models have an HTML5 capable browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking about an application running on the phone natively but written using HTML5 and Javascript, look into the WebWorks/Widget platform. It runs on Blackberry OS versions 5 and 6.

If you want to have a web site/app that uses HTML5 offline storage, it will probably only work with Blackberry OS version 6.

[This guide](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/choosingtargetos.jsp?IID=DEVTRG1222) can help in determining how much of the market is using those OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

My Answer is Yes, You can, BB5 have a extra soft internaly to do that
is GOOGLE GEAR
that support SQLLite DB

```
 if (window.openDatabase){
        //HTML5
  }else{
     //try google GEARS
     if (window.google || google.gears){
        _DB = google.gears.factory.create('beta.database', '1.0');
        _DB.open('MyLocalDB');
        }

    }
```